# Flask loads the same index.js file when running from different project

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm encountering the following problem when trying to run a flask app locally: I've used URL_FOR and directly tried specifying the path of my index.js file, but it always loads a *different* index.js when I try and run the flask app locally.

Folder setup:

```
folder with source code of sample projects from a course i'm doing
-project1
--templates
---index.html
--static
---index.js
--application.py
-project2
--templates
---index.html
--static
---index.js
--application.py
-project3
--templates
---index.html
--static
---index.js
--application.py
-...
```

--> Say I'm in project2 now in my terminal. 
I'm running export `FLASK_APP=application.py`, then `python3 -m flask run` and it serves the app on localhost 5000 as per:

`* Serving Flask-SocketIO app "application.py"
 * Forcing debug mode off`

Looks OK until now. However, here's what's interesting –> when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/, and `inspect`, it always references the index.js in my /project1/static folder.

What I'm doing in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <title>Vote</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="votes">
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <button data-vote="yes">Yes</button>
        <button data-vote="no">No</button>
        <button data-vote="maybe">Maybe</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

What my index.js looks like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // Each button should emit a "submit vote" event
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = () => {
                const selection = button.dataset.vote;
                socket.emit('submit vote', {'selection': selection});
            };
        });
    });

    // When a new vote is announced, add to the unordered list
    socket.on('announce vote', data => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = `Vote recorded: ${data.selection}`;
        document.querySelector('#votes').append(li);
    });
});
```

What my application.py looks like:

```
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("submit vote")
def vote(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    emit("announce vote", {"selection": selection}, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Answers from my end**

- I found a funny way to fix it myself: if I just rename it to "main.js" and reference that, it works.

**Questions**

- Any idea what could be wrong here? Am I referencing index.js in a wrong way?
- It can't be the case that you simply can't have multiple index.js files in one parent folder… right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the browser will cache static files. Since all your JavaScript files named `index.js`, the path in all your project will be `/static/index.js`. The browser look at the static's path, "oh, it's the same file! So I just read from cache".

So, the only thing you need to do is [clear browser cache](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic) (maybe simply with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).